# How to make Google Smart Home App suggests Smart Home Actions

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have a Google Smart Home action deployed already, and I noticed that when I open the Google Home app, there are some suggestions of apps to link to my Google Home (as shown in the image below), and those integrations are from apps that I have installed on phone, and as I add new apps that have integration with Google Home, the app start to suggest to integrate with Google Home as well.

I would like to know if it's possible to do such a thing with my native app and my Google Smart Home action.

[Google Home App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMe9F.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available for any developer to implement through [App Discovery](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/discovery).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available publicly, it is being tested with a few early partners. I would recommend monitoring our social channels so you can be notified when a feature like this becomes available to everyone.

- https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/changelog
- https://twitter.com/actionsongoogle
- https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Regarding this partnership between companies and Google, is there any way for my company to be joining Google as well?